# Android market application autoupdate

Tags: android

Some of the applications I have installed on my phone update automatically, I don't even have to click anything. This is the behavior I expect from the application I'm developing myself. Do I have to configure something or will android market take care of this?

Comment: Are you asking this question in reference to apps already on your device or an app you're _developing_?

Comment: @MarvinPinto The app I'm developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a behaviour you can set on the application itself. Each user chooses how the applications he downloads are updated. This is a market setting.

In the latest versions of the market, the default is now set to auto-update, but the user is free to untick the box and decide for manual updates, per application. If you open settings, you can also decide whether it's done on Wi-Fi only or on mobile data as well.

This will be done on all updates **except** the ones where a permission change occurred. For them, the market will still require a manual update.

Answer (score 1):

Auto update is possible. But you should click app to start it at least.
In the start process, you can send the current version status to server through web service, server will identify the version if there is new version. if yes, a new version apk file will be downloaded, and the most important is how to install a apk file sliently.

Generally, you can run the

```
pm install -r xxx.apk
```

the apk will be automatically installed, and your app will be updated.

Comment: 1) Do you mean my own server, or Google Play? 2) How do I run this: "pm install -r xxx.apk"?

Comment: Yes, you should have your own server, not Google Play.

Comment: run the "pm install -r xxx.apk"， you can search some methods to run shell in android.  I think lots of info can be found in Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive you can't force users to update their installed apps, but I think it is the default behaviour of the Android Market.